# Text input field doesn't work on smartphone

Tags: android, html, text, input, numbers

I'm developing an application in HTML5 that I'll turn in Android App (using the WebView) via Ludei Framework.
I have also a PHP page, hosted on my website, that is part of this app.
I created a link from the sidebar menu of my app that shows this page.

When I try to write something in the text field of the PHP page, I can only type numbers but not letters.
If I try to open the same page with my smartphone browser, it works great without errors!

What can I do!?
It is a problem only of the app...

I tried also using another form style, and also to include the PHP page with an iframe, but it still doesn't work...
Also it doesn't do differences between a text input field, an e-mail input field, an url input field...
It always shows the classic querty...

Thanks in advice =)

CODE OF THE PHP PAGE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
   
 <title>RoyalRadio Framework</title>
    
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/normalize.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    
 <!-- Color Scheme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/color.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>
<body> 
 
  
  <div class="st-pusher">
   <div class="st-content">
    <div class="st-content-inner">
     <!-- Top Navigation -->
     <header>
      <h1>ROYAL RADIO</h1>
     </header>
     
     <br /><br />
     <div class="content">
      <fieldset>
       <legend align="center">CONTATTACI</legend>
       
<?php
/** Includiamo la class PHPMailer */
include_once('contattaci/PHPMailer.class.php');

/**La vostra e-mail, in cui ricevere l'email */
$email_sito = 'direzione@royalradio.it';

/**Il Nome del vostro sito web */
$nome_sito = 'RoyalRadio.it';

/** Recuperiamo i dati */
$nome = $_REQUEST['nome'];
$cognome = $_REQUEST['cognome'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$telefono = $_REQUEST['telefono'];
$sito = $_REQUEST['sito'];
$messaggio = $_REQUEST['messaggio'];
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

//controlliamo i campi obbligatori
if(empty($nome) || empty($cognome) || empty($email) || empty($telefono) || empty($messaggio)) {
    echo '<p class="error">Compila tutti i campi</p>';
} else {

$msg = "<strong>IP:</strong> $IP <br />";
$msg .= "<strong>Nome:</strong> $nome <br />";
$msg .= "<strong>Cognome:</strong> $cognome <br />";
$msg .= "<strong>E-mail:</strong> $email <br />";
$msg .= "<strong>Telefono:</strong> $telefono <br />";
$msg .= "<strong>Sito Web:</strong> $sito <br />";
$msg .= "<strong>Messaggio:</strong> $messaggio <br />";

/** Istanziamo la classe PHPMailer */
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = ''.$nome.' '.$cognome.'';
$mail->AddAddress($email_sito);
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Subject = 'Nuova E-mail Da '.$nome_sito;
$mail->Body = $msg;
if($mail->Send()) echo "<p><b><center><font color=green><==> La tua e-mail &egrave; stata inviata <==></font></center></b><p>";

}
?>
       <form action="contattaci.php" method="post" id="formILC">
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="NOME*"/>
        <input type="text" name="cognome" id="cognome" placeholder="COGNOME*"/>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-MAIL*"/>
        <input type="tel" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="TELEFONO*"/>
        <input type="url" name="sito" id="sito" placeholder="SITO WEB"/>
        <textarea name="messaggio" id="messaggio" placeholder="MESSAGGIO"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name='submit' class="button" value="INVIA IL MESSAGGIO"/>
       </form>
       <br /><br />
       <center><em><strong>Quando hai terminato, premi il tasto "Indietro" per tornare all'app.</strong></em></center>
      </fieldset>
     </div>  
    </div><!-- /st-content-inner -->
   </div><!-- /st-content -->
  </div><!-- /st-pusher -->
 </div><!-- /st-container -->

 
 <script src="../js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 
 <script src="../js/lib/classie.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/lib/sidebarEffects.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should post your code if you want people to be able to help you. Otherwise, how can we tell you what's wrong?

Comment: I added it in the post.
I'm sorry! =)

Comment: Hi guys... what can I do? =(

Comment: Which field only takes numbers? All of them? or just the TELEFONO field?

Comment: All of them. But only in the all mobile...

Comment: ... only in the app mobile*